# How to have a table with multiple primary keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a table which has two foreign keys and combination of primary keys should be used as primary key, but the "SQL buddy" does not accept it ans shows multiple primary key error message,
am I doing something wrong,

Example

```
Unit
PK unit ID
unit name

Course 
PK course ID
Course Name

CourseHasUnit
FK PK CourseID
FK PK UnitID
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a composite key? Does it require more than one column to uniquely identify rows in your table?

Comment: At first glance it looks ok.  Are you writing your own create table commands or using a client of some sort?

Comment: I am using SQL Buddy which is provided by WAMP. Yes primary key should be defined using a unique combination of CourseID and UnitID

Comment: I added a mysql tag to your post to broaden the audience.  This is beyond my meager talents.

Answer (score 2):

A table cannot have two primary keys, because the definition of primary key is 'field or fixed set of fields that uniquely identifies this row'. It is meaningless to have more than one primary key by this definition, because if primary key A already uniquely identifies your rows, why would you also need primary key B?

Probably what you're trying to do is define two primary keys on CourseID and UnitID, when what you intend to do is define one primary key, composed of both fields CourseID and UnitID.

Comment: *Every* candidate key uniquely identifies rows. That is what a candidate key is, not just a primary key. Certainly things can have more than one such identifier. Far from being "meaningless", the reason you might want to have two or more keys is exactly the same as the reason you want one key: data integrity. Each key constraint guarantees that the values in that key's columns cannot be duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

You *probably* need to do something along these lines. MySQL doesn't like inline primary key and foreign key declarations. Note the additional unique constraints. Primary key and unique key constraints both identify candidate keys. Any candidate key can be the target of foreign key references.

```
create table unit (
  unit_id ... ,
  unit_name ... ,
  primary key (unit_id),
  unique key (unit_name)
);

create table course (
  course_id ... ,
  course_name ..., 
  primary key (course_id),
  unique key (course_name)
);

create table course_has_unit (
  course_id ... ,
  unit_id ... ,
  primary key (course_id, unit_id),
  foreign key (course_id) references course (course_id),
  foreign key (unit_id) references unit (unit_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution with SQLBuddy was simply to creäte the table without a primary key at all.  Once I had the table creätéd, I ran an ALTER TABLE query specifyïng the desired multicolumn primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about "composite key" because there can only be one primary key per table.

My suggestion:

Ase a autoincrement type primary key for every table. If you have multiple values that form a uniquely identifying key, then create the proper indexes and unique constraints. Do not use a composite primary key.